# Laravel 5.0 loop over items of relation in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a one to many relation like this:

1 block has many blockItems

I fetch allBlocks in my controller like this:

```
$allBlocks = Block::all();
```

I access my blockItems through my relation like this:
The relation is setup correctly I can do this in my blade:

```
@foreach($allBlocks as $block)
    @foreach($block->blockItems as $item)
        {{ $item->item_type }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now my issue in my blade I have all the Blocks and I want to loop over the blockItems of the block with id 2. I've tried this:

```
@foreach($allBlocks->where('id', 2)->blockItems as $item)
    {{ $item->item_type}}
@endforeach
```

this unfortunately displays nothing.

Comment: can you try this $allBlocks->where('id', 2)->get()->blockItems or do a dd( $allBlocks->where('id', 2))

Comment: @ElenaRoman it says Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Comment: you should not use database query in blade files. its not a good way

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
allBlocks->where('id', 2)->blockItems as $item
```

to

```
allBlocks->where('id', 2)->get() as $item->blockItems
```

You just forgot to execute your query and call the blockItems on the elements

If your query only returns 1 result (as expected by selecting by ID) you can use `first()` so you don't have to loop the result(s).

Comment: This gives me the following error: Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()

Comment: My bad, will fix

Comment: use `first` instead of `get`

Comment: @NeelBhanushali Yes it probably has only 1 result as he is selecting by ID.

Comment: if you use `get`, you need to access the relation using the `0th` index like this
`$allBlocks->where('id', 2)[0]->blockItems`
using `first`, he will be able to access relation directly.

Comment: @NeelBhanushali Yes I know or a nested loop

Answer (score 0):

You are applying where clause on a collection. You need to run a `get` or a `first` method on the collection to get items from collection as per the where clause.

`first` will get only one item and then you can access the `blockItems` relation.

```
@foreach($allBlocks->where('id', 2)->first()->blockItems as $item)
    {{ $item->item_type}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

`all` returns a collection containing `Blocks`

I don't think you need all of the existing blocks in the database but let's say that you want to.

You need to filter the `Block` you want and for each its items. You can do several approaches to filter the collection (you won't need if you have the exact data to work with, it's faster to work the query than to work with objects usually)

```
$collection->firstWhere('id', '=', 2);
```

So your code should look something like

```
@foreach($allBlocks->firstWhere('id', '=', 2)->blockItems as $item)
    {{ $item->item_type}}
@endforeach
```

> https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_all
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-first-where

Edit: Since it's Laravel 5.0, you'll need to apply the `where` condition

> https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_where

Note that it still gives you a collection according to the docs, but assuming your id is unique, you can then use `first()`.

```
$collection->where('id', '=', 2); // will result in a filtered collection, to which you can apply first()
```

Comment: I get this error unfortunately Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::firstWhere()

Comment: try just where instead of firstwhere @Michael

Comment: when I try just with where I get this error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$blockItems

Comment: You should try to read the errors and read what the documentation says @Michael, filtering a collection will return a reduced collection, read my edit

Comment: I am just gonna fetch the blockItems for every Block seperatly in my controller and send all the seperate collection to the view

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@foreach($allBlocks as $block)
    @if($block->id==2)
         @foreach($block->blockItems as $item)
               {{ $item->item_type }}
         @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```